# xcodebuild test - how to build on one machine & run the tests on another

Tags: testing, xcodebuild

Our MAC team have a XCode project with UI Automation tests which are run from the commandline with

```
xcodebuild test
```

This command both builds & executes the tests. The tests take ~30 seconds, launch UI, and executes UI logic.

However on our CI system we don't want to run the tests on our builders. Instead we want to transfer the artifacts to another dedicated testing machine.

Is it possible to build all the test code on the builder, transfer the artifacts to the tester, & then execute the tests?

This *seems* like an obvious thing for XCode to support but I've not yet found the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find an answer to this, i have the EXACT same problem :)

Comment: Ah - I've left one of those annoying unanswered questions. Unfortunately the answer is no. AFAIK it is not possible to split the tests out (unless newer versions of XCode have added this as a feature). We ended up tagging the tests onto the end of the automated debug build.

Comment: So I was looking into it, and it looks like when you just "build" the tests it puts all the relevant information into the /build/Derived Data directory.  So we are just going to build the tests and app in one place and then scp that Derived Data directory to all the other computers.  Any reason that won't work that you can think of?

Comment: None - but I'm no expert. If everything is in derived data you "should" be good. Only concern would be if a required framework is located elsewhere. Might give this a look myself once I have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

We were unable to discover a method to split the tests out. In the end we were forced to run the tests as part of the debug build. Which is not ideal.